# Adding an input value as a parameter to a hyperlink in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How should I structure the following link so that the value of SearchInput is added as a parameter?

Thanks

```
<input id="SearchInput" name="SearchInput" type="text" aria-label="Search Input" />
<a href="/search?term="[value from input]>SEARCH</a>
```

I was thinking something like this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="this.href = '/search?term=' + document.getElementById(SearchInput).value">
```